# Como fazer o teclado sumir quando clicar fora do mesmo? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Tenho um TextField normal, mas gostaria de saber como fazer o teclado do textField desaparecer quando clico fora dele. Sei fazer ele sumir clicando em return usando o delegate textFieldShouldReturn, mas gostaria de saber quando clico fora.

Comment: Você gostaria de fazer sumir o teclado ou o TextField? No título você diz o teclado e na pergunta você diz o TextField.

Comment: Ops, verdade
Desculpa a confusao, vou arrumar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma possível solução é detectar o click fora do teclado utilizando um `GestureRecognizer`. Então chamar o método `resignFirstResponder` na instância de *textfield* ou chamar `endEditing` que força qualquer descendente da view que seja o first responder a "renunciar" essa condição.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var textField : UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textField.delegate = self
        var tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func dismissKeyboard(){
        //textField.resignFirstResponder()
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Cara, perfeito!
Muito Obrigado, continue nos ajudando, :)

Comment: Otima resposta Rafael, porém tem maneiras mais fáceis de se realizar. Confira minha resposta, só para fins de aprendizado.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @Skal

Answer (score 1):

Adicione o seguinte método ao *ViewController*:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: e como pode ser adicionado no delegate?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode simplesmente fazer com que o teclado feche da seguinte maneira:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
     self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Unica coisa necessaria para funcionar é colocar o textField como delegate da View

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o método touchesBegan (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan).

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Adicionar o seu text field no código acima.

Answer (score 0):

Sair do teclado com click na tela ***Swift 4**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.dismissKeyboard)))
}

func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```